# Confidence interval for the median

Tags: standard-deviation, bootstrap, standard-error, median

I have a set of values ${x_i}, i=1, \dots ,N$ of which I calculate the median M. I was wondering how I could calculate the error on this estimation.

On the net I found that it can be calculated as $1.2533\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}$ where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation. But I did not find references about it. So I do not understand why.. Could someone explain it to me?

I was thinking that I could use bootstrap to have an estimate of the error but I would like to avoid it because it would slow down a lot my analysis.

Also I was thinking to calculate the error on the median in this way
$$\delta M = \sqrt{ \frac{\sum_i(x_i - M)^2}{N-1} } $$

Does it make sense?

Comment: Do you know with absolute certainty that the data are normally distributed?

Comment: they are lognormal

Comment: Bootstrap should work and it could not take a long time. Either you have a complete enough dataset and no need to do a bootstrap, just take the median of your variable as a good estimation of the real median. Or you have a rather small dataset and you could use bootstrap to estimate a median with your margin error in no excessive time.

Comment: You are rather looking for MAD https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation , see also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122001/confidence-intervals-for-median or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21103/confidence-interval-for-median

Comment: There is some good discussions here, as well: [https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59838/standard-error-of-the-median](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59838/standard-error-of-the-median)

Comment: Extensive information about the distribution of the median appears in my post at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/86804/919.  It develops the theory needed for both nonparametric and normal-approximation confidence intervals.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To directly deal with error on the median you can use the exact nonparametric confidence interval for the median, which uses order statistics.  If you want something different, i.e., a measure of dispersion, consider Gini's mean difference. [Code is here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186957/is-there-a-reliable-nonparametric-confidence-interval-for-the-mean-of-a-skewed-d) for the median's confidence interval.

Comment: I was actually considering to use an analog of the Gini coefficient: $S_n=c * med_j (med_j |x_i-x_j|)$ as defined by Rousseeuw and Croux (http://web.ipac.caltech.edu/staff/fmasci/home/astro_refs/BetterThanMAD.pdf).

Comment: The median must have an asymmetric error if the data distribution is asymmetric.

Answer (score 13):

As pointed out in the other answer, there is a non-parametric CI for the median using the order statistics. That CI is better in many aspects than what you found on the net.

Now, if you must know where the $1.2533\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}$ factor comes from,  the answer is from the asymptotic distribution of the median. If we denote the sample median by $\tilde{\theta}$ and the population median by $\theta$ then it can be shown that

$$\sqrt{n} \left( \tilde{\theta} - \theta \right) \xrightarrow{L} \mathcal{N} \left(0, \frac{1}{4 \left[f  \left( \theta \right) \right]^2} \right)$$

where $f$ is the distribution of your sample. The result is not as universal as the CLT because the asymptptic distribution still depends on the underlying distribution of your sample (through the term $\left[f  \left( \theta \right) \right]^2$). You can, however, make the drastic simplication that your sample comes from a normal distribution with mean -and median- $\theta$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Evaluating $f$ at its point of symmetry then yields

$$\left[f  \left( \theta \right) \right]^2 = \frac{1}{2\pi \sigma^2}$$

and so the asymptotic variance becomes

$$\frac{2\pi}{4} \sigma^2$$.

Divide by $N$ and take the square root of that to arrive at your standard error $1.2533\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}$.

Comment: now in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Sampling_distribution