# Confidence interval for the median - continued

Tags: error, median, error-propagation

I have a set of values $x_i\quad i=1,…,N$ of which I can calculate the median M. Each $x_i$ has an error $\delta x_i$. 
The $x_i$ values are the result of a maximum likelyhood estimation and their error is calculated using the [Cramer-Rao inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound).

How could I proceed to calculate the error on the median $\delta M$?

Some time ago I asked a similar [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/196658/confidence-interval-for-the-median?noredirect=1#comment373022_196658) but at the time I did not consider the error on the $x_i$ values. How this additional uncertainty modifies the answer/way of thinking?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what an "error" is?  Unless those errors can be translated into something like a joint distribution, or at a minimum can be given finite bounds, then obtaining an objective answer looks hopeless.