mean of medians consistently differs from median
Disclaimer: my first question here.
Background of the problem:
I want to compare two distributions (n1 ~ 500 and n2 ~ 700), not normal and with different variances, but roughly unimodal. I decided to use the median for comparitive statistics.
Using (scipy's) permutation test I got a p-value for the observed difference of the two medians. Using the also generated null hypothesis distribution I was able to get the minimal detectable effects of the experiment as well.
I want to estimate the error (-> error bars for plotting) of the observed difference (of the medians). So I use np.random.choice to draw two new distribution with same sizes and repeats/replace; but without mixing between the groups (i.e. assuming the effect / observed difference is real). I calculated the difference of the medians of the two new distributions and repeated all of that 100000 times.
Problem
Over all these realisation I calculated the mean and std and found that the mean (of the differences of medians) is consistenly off by ca 13% compared to the difference of the median of the originial data.
Is that a bug, test-design error or an actually possible result? If it is the last, why and what does it imply?
Code
# raw experimental data: A, B
# drawing new distributions a, b without mixing
a = np.random.choice(A, (100000, len(A), True)  
b = np.random.choice(B, (100000, len(B), True)
med_m = np.mean(np.median(a, axis = 1) - np.median(b, axis = 1))
med_s = np.std(np.median(a, axis = 1) - np.median(b, axis = 1))
med = np.median(A) - np.median(B)

med_m / med
>>> 1.13...
```


Your a and b code line have more brackets open than closed.

I'd probably run this with very small toy data sets and a very small number of replicates and then look at all objects to see whether they are what I think they should be. This helps to understand what is going on.

Theoretically the difference between your means of medians cannot be guaranteed to be equal to the difference between medians. A counterexample would be if one data set has 51% 1 and 49% 0, and the other has 49% 1 and 51% 0. The difference between medians then would be 1-0=1, but if you randomly draw from these, you will occasionally observe medians 0 (data 1) and/or 1 (data 2), so the difference between means of medians will be systematically smaller than 1.

You could implement some of the methodological alternatives provided here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/502977/confidence-interval-for-median-which-is-more-appropriate-bootstrap-or-binom-ex

This is a consequence of the fact that the expected value of the sample median is not, in general, equal to the population median if the underlying distribution is not symmetric -i.e., the sample median is not, in general, an unbiased estimator of the population median.
Consider, for example, an Exponentially-distributed variable with rate $= 1$.  The population median $= \ln 2$. However, due to the asymmetry of the Exponential distribution, the distribution of the sample median is not symmetric around the true median:
sample_median <- rep(0,10000)
for (j in seq_along(sample_median)) {
    x <- rexp(11)
    sample_median[j] <- median(x)
}

hist(sample_median)


and, heuristically, due to the fact that "high" medians are likely to be farther from the population median than "low" medians are, the expected value is larger than the true median:
> t.test(sample_median, mu=log(2))

    One Sample t-test

data:  sample_median
t = 13.576, df = 9999, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0.6931472
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.7290101 0.7411145
sample estimates:
mean of x 
0.7350623 

